# proxy server software for windows xp

Tags: windows, windows-xp, proxy

Is there a proxy software for Windows XP that can support HTTP, HTTPS, SMTP, IMAP, POP, FTP, etc. (the more the better)?

We tried apache mod_proxy but FTP doesn't work through it (at least not all features).

Maybe we don't need proxy server for following requirements (we are open for suggestions):
- Centralized access point to internet for several users (proxy server?)
- Users use Browser (firefox/IE - HTTP, HTTPS), Outlook (SMTP, POP, IMAP)
- Logs to see where did users go on internet
- Possiblity to connect to FTP server

Windows xp, which is used as proxy server, is a virtual machine, and all other users/clients are virtual machines as well (Hyper-V)...

Thanks for suggestions.

Cheers

Comment: What is the relationship between a proxy server and mail protocols?!?

Comment: why do you need a proxy server on a workstation OS? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The goal would be to "limit" Internet access to users. With apache and mod_proxy we can see which sites did the users visit, traffic,  etc. We've set it up on Windows XP because it was the simplest solution.

Comment: This sounds wrong in *so many* ways...

Comment: Hi Massimo, thank you for your comment, would you be so kind to propose a solution for following requirements:
- Centralized access point to internet for several users (proxy server?)
- Users use Browser (firefox/IE - HTTP, HTTPS), Outlook (SMTP, POP, IMAP)
- Logs to see where did users go on internet
- Possiblity to connect to FTP server

Thanks

Comment: @This: done, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) A "proxy server" is something that handles web traffic (sometimes FTP too); but it's something completely unrelated to mail protocols, and to any other type of traffic, actually. If you want to filter/monitor *all* Internet traffic, you don't want a proxy: you want a firewall (or a software that combines both, such as ISA Server).

2) Running this type of service on a workstation O.S. such as Windows XP is just plainly **wrong**; and I'm willing to bet you want to do this because you want to run it on workstation *hardware*, too. What if it stops? What if it goes down? What if it breaks? Ops... no Internet access anymore.

3) There *are* firewall/proxy products for Windows (ISA/TMG is the first that comes to mind), but they usually require a server version of Windows, and they don't come for free. If you want free software you could look at some Windows porting of Squid or something like that, but then, why don't you just run this on Linux? Every Linux distribution comes with built-in firewall capabilities, and Squid is usually already installed, or really easy to add.

My suggestion: if you want Windows, use Windows Server 2003 with ISA Server 2006, or Windows Server 2008 with TMG 2010; but be prepared to spend some money on them. Otherwise, just use Linux.

Comment: Thanks Massimo, what you have described is real deal solution. But, we would like to avoid linux (squid especially) and we are also not too keen on spending money on server and additional software. Do you know for some other solution which would fit on XP (even if it is not free)? Thanks again.

Comment: None that I'm aware of.

Comment: OK. But, for what would you use apache mod_proxy then? Is it really that bad to use apache mod_proxy for above mentioned requirements? Thanks

Comment: It would be totally useless for your requirements; it can only handle HTTP(S) and FTP, and it's generally more oriented to publishing web sites than to managing user access to Internet. In the open source world, the default proxy server is Squid.